# Elasticsearch: execute a filter on nested document only if it exists

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using ES 2.3 and have a query in which `filter` section looks as follows:

```
"filter": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "employees",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [ 
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "employees.max_age": {
                          "lte": 50
                        }
                      }
                    }, 
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "employees.min_age": {
                          "gte": 20
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }, 
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "employees"
            }
          },
          {
            #....other filter here based on root document, not on nested employee document
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a filter, where I check some conditions in the nested document "employees" in a bigger document called company, But I want to run this filter, only if "employees" object exists, as some of the document may not have that nested document at all. So I added , `{"exists": {"field": "employees"}}`
but this doesn't seem to work. Any idea what change I should make to get it work?

Comment: You need to move the `exists` query inside the `nested` query and it will work

Comment: @Val can you  please show me where should i exactly put it?

Comment: Also if you put it inside `nested` then you are already assuming nested already exist, then only it will traverse?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. However, if documents don't have the `employees` field, they will not be picked up anyway, so I'm not sure why you want/need that `exists` query in the first place.

```
{
  "filter": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "employees",
              "query": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "employees"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "employees",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "employees.max_age": {
                          "lte": 50
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "employees.min_age": {
                          "gte": 20
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @val I will try this and will let you know. Regarding "However, if documents don't have the employees field, they will not be picked up anyway, so I'm not sure why you want/need that exists query in the first place." - Because I want to include those documents, even where `employees` doesn't exist. What I wanted is if and only if `employees` exists, then only run the filter.

Comment: In that case it depends on how your overall query looks like, we'll see.